# How can I select mutliple entries from drop down menus?

Tags: sharepoint-online

How can I select mutliple entries from drop down menus (with data validation) into a cell in excel sharepoint? I have only been able to replace and populate single selections from my drop down menus.

Answer (score 0):

To select multiple items in the drop down list in excel, you could add the VBA code in excel.

For more detailed information, refer to the articles below.

[How to Make Multiple Selections in a Drop Down List in Excel.](https://trumpexcel.com/select-multiple-items-drop-down-list-excel/)

[Excel Data Validation - Select Multiple Items.](https://www.contextures.com/excel-data-validation-multiple.html)